# How to handle JS error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="row">
        <td style="width: 88%;">
            <input id="hdnPackageProuctId" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("ID")%>'  />
            <div style="float:left; margin-top:5px;height:18px;">
                 <input type="radio" id="ChkIsProduct" name="chkProductsList" onclick="hdnSelectedProdName.value='<%# HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Eval("Name"))%>'; hdnSelectedProdID.value='<%# Eval("ID")%>';"     />&nbsp; 
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;font-size:12px;margin-top:5px; font-weight:bold; width:300px;height:18px;"  class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvtruncate" title='<%# Eval("Name")%>'>  
                <%# Eval("Name")%>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width: 12%;">
           <div id="dvPrice" class="gvColSet tLightBlack gvColAlignLeft" style="font-size:12px; float:left; width:95px;  "><%# FormatNumber(Eval("SalePrice"), 2)%></div>`enter code here`
           <input id="hdnUnitPrice" type="hidden" value='<%# FormatNumber(Eval("SalePrice"), 2)%>' />
        </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is item template of repeater but when I click on check box:

```
onclick="hdnSelectedProdName.value = '<%# HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Eval("Name"))%>';
hdnSelectedProdID.value='<%# Eval("ID")%>';
```

there are JS error occured I try my best but unable to find.

Comment: Post more details. Explain what are you trying to achieve. What is it that you want to do on clicking the checkbox? Is this checkbox outside the repeater??

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: First, I don't see any item with ID `hdnSelectedProdName`. Second, I assume since I'm seeing an `<ItemTemplate>` tag here there is going to be more of these? If that is the case, your IDs will no longer be unique: `hdnPackageProuctId`, `dvPrice`, `hdnUnitPrice` will all be duplicated. I think you need to refactor your code

Comment: Run on mozilla and press ctrl+shift+J. this will open error console and enlists error if occured

Comment: it is item template of repeater actually  there are a checkbox when i click on that I assigin some value to hidden field as shown in code and when I click on that there are js error hdnSelectedProdName not found

Answer (score 0):

need

```
onclick="hdnSelectedProdName.value = '<%# HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Eval(\"Name\"))%>';
hdnSelectedProdID.value='<%# Eval(\"ID\")%>';
```

Comment: can you tell me please why add \ in \"ID\"